# How to use Postgres JSONB datatype with JPA?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

Im not finding a way to map the JSON and JSONB datatypes from PostgreSQL using JPA (EclipseLink). Is some one using this datatypes with JPA and can give me some working examples?

Comment: There is an example somewhere on SO, let me see if i can find...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All the answers helped me to reach the final solution that is ready for JPA and not EclipseLink or Hibernate specifically.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import org.postgresql.util.PGobject;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class JsonConverter implements javax.persistence.AttributeConverter<JsonObject, Object> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Override
  public Object convertToDatabaseColumn(JsonObject objectValue) {
    try {
      PGobject out = new PGobject();
      out.setType("json");
      out.setValue(objectValue.toString());
      return out;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to serialize to json field ", e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public JsonObject convertToEntityAttribute(Object dataValue) {
    try {
      if (dataValue instanceof PGobject && ((PGobject) dataValue).getType().equals("json")) {
        return mapper.reader(new TypeReference<JsonObject>() {
        }).readValue(((PGobject) dataValue).getValue());
      }
      return Json.createObjectBuilder().build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to deserialize to json field ", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried something like this for Hibernate, but it seems `AttributeConverter` that ends up with `Object` is broken with `Hibernate`. I just get an error saying "unknown jdbc type" or something like that. Shame really, since this approach is much prettier, with less boiler plate.

Comment: I didn't need this yesterday when the question was asked, I need it today and tried your solution, only to discover that the Postgres JDBC driver wants it through a special method `setPGobject`, which can only be called manually or if you use `setObject` you have to specify the type to `java.sql.Types.OTHER`, which I can't do. I modified the driver to send it there if unknown and the right class, only to run into ClassLoader conflicts. If I load the driver in the webapp I get conflict when loading, but not setting. If I load it in the `tomcat/lib` directory, I get the conflict when setting.

Comment: @coladict The class i posted isn´t working for you? I din´t understand your problem very well. If you see the method convertToDatabaseColumn it will return an Object but this object is already of type PGobject necessary for Postgres i dont think you need anything more than that.

Comment: Technically, you're right that it should work. There is no good reason for the webapp and the server to be loading the class from different ClassLoaders, but they are doing it.

Comment: PGobject is the class that is being loaded from different places? Try to see if you are not importing the packages two times one directly and one by maven.

Comment: First I put the pgjdbc driver dependency in `pom.xml` as compile (include in war) and deployed on Tomcat 8.5 (older versions don't search the war for jdbc drivers) without having it in it's `lib` path, so it could only have found it in the `war`. The classloader conflict occurred when the pgjdbc driver tried to persist an entity. Then I put it in as `provided` scope, so it's not included in the war, and added the jar in `tomcat/lib`. The conflict was when I read an entity. The problem is from Tomcat. It might work right under Glassfish or another server.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with Hibernate (current 5.2.10.Final). The error is `org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: SOME_RANDOM_NUMBER` and apparently developers are not going to fix it. The proposed by them solution is using Generic Hibernate Types (heavy stuff) https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/06/20/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/

Comment: @SewerynNiemiec Are you using JPA right? This solution is for using with JPA and not with specific dialect HQL from Hibernate. Is that your case?

Comment: Yes, I'm using JPA interface. All my custom AttributeConverters which use standard SQL types work without problems. The one for jsonb gave my the error.

Comment: You have to replace mapper.read by mapper.readFor as mapper.read is deprecated.

Comment: For me it doesn't work, I've the same problem that @coladict when using Hibernate implementation.  The problem is that when calling PGPreparedStatement.setObject with the PGObject Types.OTHER isn't used. Anyone had that problem and find any solution?

Comment: @lujop since then I have made a [plug-and-play library for using these json object types](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-json-contributor). It will work for Hibernate 5.2 and above before 6.0. It will NOT work with Hibernate 6.0. Tested with postgresql and mysql databases.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: I see now that this is pretty much `Hibernate` dependent. But perhaps you can find something similar for `EclipseLink`.

I'll just add what I have as an answer, it originates from another SO answer but whatever. This will map `jsonb` to `JsonObject` of Google `gson`, but you can change it to something else if needed. To change to something else, change `nullSafeGet`, `nullSafeSet`and `deepCopy` methods.

```
public class JsonbType implements UserType {

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.JAVA_OBJECT };
    }

    @Override
    public Class<JsonObject> returnedClass() {
        return JsonObject.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) {
        if (x == y) {
            return true;
        }
        if (x == null || y == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(final Object x) {
        if (x == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet rs,
                              final String[] names,
                              final SessionImplementor session,
                              final Object owner) throws SQLException {
        final String json = rs.getString(names[0]);
        if (json == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        return jsonParser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement st,
                            final Object value,
                            final int index,
                            final SessionImplementor session) throws SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            st.setNull(index, Types.OTHER);
            return;
        }

        st.setObject(index, value.toString(), Types.OTHER);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(@Nullable final Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        return jsonParser.parse(value.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(final Object value) {
        final Object deepCopy = deepCopy(value);

        if (!(deepCopy instanceof Serializable)) {
            throw new SerializationException(
                    String.format("deepCopy of %s is not serializable", value), null);
        }

        return (Serializable) deepCopy;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object assemble(final Serializable cached, final Object owner) {
        return deepCopy(cached);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object replace(final Object original, final Object target, final Object owner) {
        return deepCopy(original);
    }
}
```

To use this, do:

```
public class SomeEntity {

    @Column(name = "jsonobject")
    @Type(type = "com.myapp.JsonbType") 
    private JsonObject jsonObject;
```

In addition, you need to set your dialect to indicate that `JAVA_OBJECT` = `jsonb`:

```
registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonb");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I found an analogy to Hibernate's UserType for EclipseLink.

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/jpa/extensions/annotations_ref.htm#CHDEHJEB

You have to make a class that implements `org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.Converter` and does the conversion for you, then use the `@Convert` annotation on every field where you are using that type.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a Mysql solution with the JSON column type, here it is. FWIW I am using EclipseLink but this is a pure JPA solution.

```
@Column(name = "JSON_DATA", columnDefinition="JSON")
@Convert(converter=JsonAttributeConverter.class)
private Object jsonData;
```

and

```
@Converter
public class JsonAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter <Object, String>
{

    private JsonbConfig cfg = new JsonbConfig().withFormatting(true);

    private Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(cfg);
    
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object object)
    {      
        if (object == null) return null;

        return jsonb.toJson(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String value)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        return jsonb.fromJson(value, value.getClass());
    }

}
```