# How to put JSONB throught Postgres database with JPA

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to build an REST application using Jersey, Gson, JPA and I would like to put a JSON object to [JSON or JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) database field into Postgres.

I tried to do something like this : [How to use Postgres JSONB datatype with JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830842/how-to-use-postgres-jsonb-datatype-with-jpa#answer-39885334) but my table see a 'VARCHAR' type instead of 'JSONB'.

My Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "votes")

public class Votes {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private int idSocialChoice;

@Convert(converter=JsonConverter.class)
private JsonObject vote;

public Votes() {
}

public JsonObject getVote() {
    return vote;
}

public void setVote(JsonObject vote) {
    this.vote = vote;
}

public int getIdSocialChoice() {
    return idSocialChoice;
}

public void setIdSocialChoice(int idSocialChoice) {
    this.idSocialChoice = idSocialChoice;
}
```

How i insert my entity :

```
Votes votes0 = new Votes();
votes0.setIdSocialChoice(3);

JsonObject object = Json.createObjectBuilder().build();
votes0.setVote(object);

List<Votes> listvotes = new ArrayList<Votes>();
listvotes.add(votes0);

ModelEntities.insertVotes(listvotes);
```

Method insertVotes :

```
public static void insertVotes(List<Votes> animalList) {

    CrudServiceBean crudServiceBean = new CrudServiceBean(CrudServiceBean.PU_DB);
    crudServiceBean.newTransaction();

    for(Votes votes : animalList)
        crudServiceBean.create(votes);

    crudServiceBean.commit();

    crudServiceBean.closeTransaction();

}
```

Method create of crudServiceBean.create :

```
public  <T> T create(T t) {
    this.em.persist(t);
    this.em.flush();
    this.em.refresh(t);
    return t;
}
```

My JPA provider create my the schema like this (createDDL_ddlGeneration.sql) :

```
CREATE TABLE votes (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, IDSOCIALCHOICE INTEGER, VOTE VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

I would also avoid to use Hibernate.

Thank you.

Comment: "it does not work" (TM). I'm sure something must happen, maybe an exception, maybe an SQL in the log, but saying "it does not work" is little use for people here diagnosing your problem

Comment: @NeilStockton I've add the class JsonConverter to my project but i don't know which annotation i need to put in my Entity attribut value. So for now i have "'Basic' attribut type should not be a map" over the attribut.

Comment: You follow a JPA AttributeConverter guide such as http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#attributeconverter to configure it. And if you get some exception then you state in your question the exception+stack trace and which JPA provider

Comment: @NeilStockton Ok i've added the annotation needed. Know everything work fine except that my database detect a 'BYTEA' instead of 'jsonb'

Comment: which means what? You created your schema? or your JPA provider created it? in which case POST the schema that was created, and by what process. And then the SQL used

Comment: @NeilStockton I've edit my post. Finally, i have a VARCHAR(255) instead of 'jsonb'.

Comment: consequently if your JPA provider doesnt create the preferred JDBC/SQL type for your column then you need to specify it in the JPA mapping (such as `@Column`)

Comment: @NeilStockton Thank you for all :). This was exactly that i have missed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have finally found the problem. I have forgetten this line on my attribute :

```
@Column (nullable = true, columnDefinition = "jsonb")
```