# How to handle 'jsonb' in JPA

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa

How I can handle a field in PostgreSQL whit datatype 'jsonb'.

I want to map it to an entity and use it whit a JPQL Query (check if a field exists with the given ID)

It should be performant as possible.

[image]

Comment: @AndyGuibert In PostgreSQL database it's possible to choose it as datatype

Comment: Have a look here : https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830842/how-to-use-postgres-jsonb-datatype-with-jpa