# How to map an org.json JSONObject to postgres jsonb datatype in java jpa entity

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jpa, jsonb

I have a JSONObject as shown below, in which the fields may vary at run time. I need to map this to a jsonb datatype field in postgres using jpa entity and to retrieve the same to JSONOject using JPARepository.

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
     jsonObj.put("name", "Tom");
     jsonObj.put("birthday", "1940-02-10");
     jsonObj.put("age", 76);
     jsonObj.put("married", false);
     jsonObj.put("favorite_foods", new String[] { "cookie", "fish", 
     "chips" });
```

Comment: First, I'm pretty sure you can't do that if you want to have `String[]` array in there - use `JSONArray`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Postgres JSONB datatype with JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830842/how-to-use-postgres-jsonb-datatype-with-jpa)

Comment: The above solution didn't work for me as it ends up in the  same error mentioned by Seweryn Niemiec. But find a solution using JsonNode as a custom usertype (SqlTypeDescriptor).

Comment: If your solution works, do post it on quesion I linked (assuming it's not posted already there, otherwise - upvote the answer you've used).